# Type of concrete class in base class with generic in c#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, types, mapping

I'm creating a method who perfomn a map between a dto and an entity overrided from a base class. I have the following classes in AuthorDto.cs and Dto.cs

```
public class AuthorDto : Dto<AuthorDto, Author>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public override void Map(IMap<AuthorDto, Author> mapper)
    {
        mapper.Map(t => t.FullName, t => t.Name + " " + t.LastName);
    }
}

public abstract class Dto<TDto, TEntity> where TDto : class where TEntity : class
{      
    public virtual void Map(IMap<TDto, TEntity> mapper) { }
}
```

I need to ensure when I override the base Map Method the first argument of the IMap parameter have to be the actual concrete class of Dto.

There is another way to perform this without to explicity indicates the first parameter in the Dto, getting the inheritance like

```
public class AuthorDto : Dto<Author>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying you want to constrain the TDto type to be the inheriting class?

```
public abstract class Dto<TDto, TEntity> where TDto : Dto<TDto, TEntity> where TEntity : class
```

This will ensure that the TDto is a class inheriting from your base Dto class.

You will not be able to inherit without explicitly defining the TDto type parameter as it must be known to the Map method.